# Choosing e and d in RSA

Tags: number-theory

I just finished watching a video explaining RSA where the following example was used:

Choose two random prime numbers:

$$P=2, Q=7$$

compute $n = pq$

$$2\times7 = 14$$

Compute the totient $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$

$$6\times 1 = 6$$

Choose $e$ that $e > 1$ and coprime to $6$

$$e=5$$

choose $d$ to satisfy $de \equiv 1 \pmod {\phi (n)}$

$$5d \equiv 1 \pmod 6$$

The instructor then goes on to say d may have multiple solutions $5,11,17, \ldots$

but the example I read prior to the video indicated that d had a unique solution.  Please help.

Comment: The 'unique' (or, rather, 'canonical') value of $d$ is the unique element of $\varphi(n)$ which is a multiplicative inverse for $e$ modulo $\varphi(n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a unique solution $\bmod 6$, but any value $5+6k$ is from the same equivalence class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason.  If I understand correctly any element from that equivalence class would work as d (the decryption exponent) .

Comment: Yes, the idea is that $1 \equiv x^6 \equiv x^{12} \equiv x^{18} \ldots \pmod n$ for any $x$, since $\phi(n) = 6$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm not able to upvote your answer because I'm new or I would.

Comment: (for any $x$ such that $\gcd(x,14) = 1$, that is)

Answer (score -1):

In general, take a prime number such as a fixed one like a Mersenne number or a prime using a primality test.

Comment: that's not what he asked